# Mingw and Boost::Log: Building trivial example fails

Tags: c++, boost, mingw

I've downloaded the mingw distro from http://nuwen.net/mingw.html and tried to build the trivial example from the [Boost::Log documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial.html#log.tutorial.trivial). This results in the following (linker?) error:

```
C:\log>g++ -lboost_log main.cpp -o logtest.exe
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\cc5rtLIQ.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::trivial::logger::get()'
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\cc5rtLIQ.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::trivial::logger::get()'
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\cc5rtLIQ.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::trivial::logger::get()'
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\cc5rtLIQ.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x105): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::trivial::logger::get()'
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\cc5rtLIQ.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x18f): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::trivial::logger::get()'
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\cc5rtLIQ.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1ac): more undefined references to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::trivial::logger::get()' follow
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\cc5rtLIQ.o: bad reloc address 0x148 in section `.rdata'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

g++'s version is 4.8.1.

I've also tried building the example with a custom-build boost library, both with the mingw compiler from [Mingw-builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/) and the mingw-get installer. The mingw-builds one show the same error messages, the version from mingw-get can't even build Boost::Log.

How can I get the logging library to work with mingw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your command line:

```
g++ main.cpp -lboost_log -o logtest.exe
```

The arguments are processed in the order specified and symbols are resolved from libraries only when the library is encountered.

Comment: @Geier: well, it clearly shows that the first set of errors got resolved and now you need to provide the other libraries used by `boost_log`!

Comment: Oh! Thanks, that was it! Full command line for reference: `g++ main.cpp -lboost_log -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread -o logtest.exe`

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to compile the boost log trivial example in gcc (linux) using the following command line:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -lboost_log -lpthread
```